# Camera (/dev/video0) dependencies in systemd service Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: console, ubuntu-16.04, systemd, udev

I need to run some services on boot up which I have successfully accomplished using systemd services. (Lots of answers already available).

Now, one of my service requires access to `/dev/video0` while bootup when a certain user is logged in. (I am doing auto login which is working fine).
So how do I check that whether the `/dev/video0` is available before starting my systemd service while bootup.

I came across something called `udev` for doing this, I followed [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186899/how-to-wait-for-a-dev-video0-before-starting-a-service)
but I am not getting desired output as after editing `/lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules` files as mentioned in the link and starting my service manually it's not starting, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally after struggling for a day I found the answer - 
I made a script in /etc/systemd/system which contains

```
[Unit]
Description='some description of my file write according to you'
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart='path to script'
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and It executes a script which contains

```
#!/bin/bash
modprobe uvcvideo
```

Now after rebooting all the services are running properly 
mod probe uvcvideo command check for running video driver and enable it at the time of bootup so that It is available for my systemd process

Thanks

Comment: This can be simplified by calling `modprobe` directly from `ExecStart`: `ExecStart=/sbin/modprobe uvcvideo`